# Splash screen in blender 2.79b

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I want to change my splash screen image.but I cant found where is the `bl_app_template_user` location.I dont found the default splash screen image in that folder

[image: location]

this is my zip file

[image: zip]

im using windows 7 professional 64 bit
thanks alot

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible without building blender from source.

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla you need to vote to close as duplicate, instead posting this.

Comment: @Crantisz already flagged it

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla I see only my vote